# How to correct divs not at the same level

Tags: html, css

How to put these two divs side by side. I used inline-block but the right one is lower than the left one. I used this same twice and in both cases this produced the same error.

Here is my html:

```
 <div class="MainHeader">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="/index.html"><img class="Logo" src="/assets/img/Logo/Logo.png"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="SPortal_header">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>| Sign Out</a></li>
                    <li>| Academic Calendar</li>
                    <li>Master Schedule</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="name_wrapper">
            <div class="student_icon">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="student_name">
                <h2>User's Name</h2>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.Logo{
    width: 270px;
    height: 50px;
    
}
.MainHeader{
    background-color: #5D0C1D;
    width: 100%;
}
.SPortal_header, .logo{
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 48%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Exactly which divs are you wanting side by side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `vertical-align: middle;` to align both inline-block divs in `middle, side-by-side`. I also removed `height: 80px;` because both of divs have different content height

```css
.Logo{
    width: 270px;
    height: 50px;
    
}
.MainHeader{
    background-color: #5D0C1D;
    width: 100%;
}
.SPortal_header, .logo{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 38%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainHeader">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="/index.html"><img class="Logo" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/389/536/354.jpg?hmac=mw2HAbrZOUQP05D91hdDGU3_1rhX_Hl8a2At_atV3PA"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="SPortal_header">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>| Sign Out</a></li>
                    <li>| Academic Calendar</li>
                    <li>Master Schedule</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="name_wrapper">
            <div class="student_icon">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="student_name">
                <h2>User's Name</h2>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```